# Почему у меня не получается передать переменную в Mail?

Tags: php, laravel

Как мне передать переменную `$email`
 в Mail ? И почему она так не передается ? а только нужно писать например

```
$message->to('gogo@gmail.com', 'gogo@gmail.com')->subject('Login and Password');
```

Она почему-то `undefined variable`

```
$email = 'gogo@gmail.com';
Mail::send('mail.mail', $data, function($message) {
            $message->to($email, $email)->subject('Login and Password');
            $message->from('tests@gro.com','tests@gro.com');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$email = 'gogo@gmail.com';
Mail::send('mail.mail', $data, function($message) use ($email) {
    $message->to($email, $email)->subject('Login and Password');
    $message->from('tests@gro.com','tests@gro.com');
});
```

Нужно передать переменную в Closure

`use ($email)`